# Do enchantments played by my opponent on creatures I control count towards my devotion?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If my opponent enchants my [Spellheart Chimera](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spellheart%20Chimera) with [Encrust](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Encrust), will Encrust be counted towards my devotion or his?

This is for devotion towards my god, [Keranos, God of Storms](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Keranos%2C%20God%20of%20Storms).

Comment: Who controls an Enchantment has no relation to who controls that which it enchants. For example, if your opponent's [Ocular Halo](http://magiccards.info/di/en/28.html) was attached to your creature, you could tap your creature to draw a card, but you couldn't give it Vigilance. Only your opponent can do that.

Answer (score 6):

Let's have a look at what devotion is:

> **Devotion**
>
> A numerical value a player has, equal to the number of mana symbols of a certain color among the mana costs of **permanents that player controls**.

The fact that Encrust is attached to your Chimera does not make you its controller. Your opponent still controls the enchantment, so Encrust will count towards your opponent's devotion to blue. You can take control of enemy's Enchantments with something like [Confiscate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=83037).

Answer (score 5):

Encrust will count toward your opponent's devotion.

This is because your opponent is the controller of Encrust, and Devotion looks at the mana symbols in the costs of permanents each player controls.

> 303.4e An Aura’s controller is separate from the enchanted object’s controller or the enchanted player; the two need not be the same. If an Aura enchants an object, changing control of the object doesn’t change control of the Aura, and vice versa.

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote?